# How does a Silverlight client access Azure stored data?

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, azure

I am thinking of developing a Silverlight application and want to make use of Windows Azure for the data storage (as well as scalability etc). But I am not sure how to get data to and from Azure using Silverlight. What technologies should I be investigating? What is the recommended approach for this scenario?

Should I be looking at using the Entity Framework from Silverlight? But then how would the EF get data from Azure and even more importantly get changes saved back again? Or do I need to go for something more custom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [.NET RIA Services](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=76bb3a07-3846-4564-b0c3-27972bcaabce&displaylang=en):

[Build a Simple Application with .Net RIA Services (Silverlight 3)](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2009/04/04/build-a-simple-application-with-net-ria-services-silverlight-3.aspx)

[Creating applications with .NET RIA Service Part 1 - Introduction](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Creating-applications-with-.NET-RIA-Service-Part-1-Introduction.aspx)

Comment: DOes it work with Windows Azure? Can I use Azure to host and provide the Data?

Comment: Yes. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/windowsazure/thread/1dbb09e7-6742-4e08-8a44-b870dd98b424

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you're going to use Azure Table Storage to store the data and Blob storage if you have really large (> 64K) data elements. Table Storage and Blob Storage have REST interfaces, and you should look at the StorageClient sample in the Azure SDK as a way to CRUD the data.  You can use these interfaces (Table and Blob) exclusively if you don't plan on exposing a public API.

However, lets say you want to be the next Twitter, and you want to expose a REST interface to the public... Even though Azure Table Storage has it's own REST interface, you create a small WCF service in a web role that exposes some specific WCF methods in a more compelling way.  You can also publish your data in JSON, which could be more useful to non-Windows data consumers.

Here's a page that I found really helpful:

[Azure Application Part 3: Expose (REST) Web Service And Consume in Silverlight](http://blogs.msdn.com/bags/archive/2009/04/17/azure-application-part-3-expose-rest-web-service-and-consume-in-silverlight.aspx).

And if you'd like to see my example, http://www.netalerts.mobi/traffic exposes data that's stored in Azure Table Storage.  http://www.netalerts.mobi/traffic/api.aspx describes the REST apis that are public.  In my implementation I call Table Storage via REST, manipulate the data, and then serve it up again in the public api.

Comment: Hi ChrisW, Can you post the link to the netalerts website. It seems its down.